# Mostrar todas las tablas en filas a columnas

Tags: postgresql

Quiero hacer un vacuum full a todas las tablas de un esquema, tengo este query que me muestra todas las tablas:

```
SELECT 'vacuum full '
       || table_name
       || ';'
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
ORDER  BY table_schema,
          table_name;
```

Me da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que realmente me gustaría que me diera sería algo así:

**vacuum full tabla1, tabla2, tabla3, tabla4;**

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hola podría usara la función STRING_AGG()

> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/

En su caso quiere agrupar las tablas por esquema.

Una posible solución seria así:

```
SELECT table_schema , 'vacuum full ' || string_agg(table_name, '; ') as "names_table"
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema = 'public'
group by (table_schema);
```